How could I set 8CONNECTED into gdal.Polygonize()
I've seen in several web pages and examples the next snippet:
gdal.Polygonize(band, maskband, polygonizedLayer, ndField, [], callback=None) but I don't understand how to use the options parameter. In the examples everybody uses this [].
Could anybody explain me how to set connectness 8?

That function is not well documented. But looking at the C docs and the tests, I can see that it's a list of options and values as strings, i.e. ["option_name=value", "another_option=value"].  The only two options supported are

8CONNECTED=8: May be set to "8" to use 8 connectedness. Otherwise 4 connectedness will be applied to the algorithm
DATASET_FOR_GEOREF=dataset_name: Name of a dataset from which to read
the geotransform.

So to set 8CONNECTED you would use use ["8CONNECTED=8"]:
gdal.Polygonize(band, maskband, polygonizedLayer, ndField, ["8CONNECTED=8"], callback=None)

To set both options, you would use use
["8CONNECTED=8", "DATASET_FOR_GEOREF=path/to/dataset"]

